# Issue with select,press and move of custom Graphics Line item

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I have created my own custom QGraphicsLineItem. The custom graphics line item will rotate and resize when mouse is clicked on the end points of line.

The problem is that the line is not easily selectable and movable. The mouse press event is not getting detected easily. I have put debug statement in my mousePressEvent but it gets called very randomly. I have set the falgs for selectable and movable.

I did not reimplement the boundingRect() and shape() but calling the parent QGraphicsLineItem's methods inside my custom line item. Could you please let me know the problem why the mouse press event is not getting detected easily on a single click on either end points of the line item?

Answer (score -1):

> ***I did not reimplement the boundingRect() and shape()***

this will your problem. the mouseEvent of QGraphicsItem is bound to the boundingregion you defined in boundingRect(). shape() is not required .

Comment: But I am calling the parent's QGraphicLineItem::boundingRect() inside the boundingRect of custom line item and nothing else. Isn't it sufficient?

Comment: @Wagmare- Thanks a lot!!!,It works well now. But why shouldn't the shape be re implemented as well? Any specific reason?

Comment: shape() probably you can use when you have a non linear or different shape of items  ex: free form draw, polygon , star, some shape like mouse any thing where you cant specify its shape as a rectangle. consider u draw a star . the boundingRect() will give you a complete rect and user can click any where outside the actual painted star area . but shape will give a polygon (a shape of your star)

Comment: from docs: The default implementation calls boundingRect() to return a simple rectangular shape, but subclasses can reimplement this function to return a more accurate shape for non-rectangular items. For example, a round item may choose to return an elliptic shape for better collision detection. but in your case it is just  a line which can be defined easily in boundingRect()